# javascript check if the values ​of an array are present as a key in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to detect if the values ​​of an array are present in an object as a key

I tried this way

```
var color = {
             1: "Red",
             2: "Blue",
             3: "Yellow",
             4: "Violet",
             5: "Green",
             7: "Orange"
            };

var myColor = [3, 1];

for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(color)){

    var bgIco = (myColor.includes(key)) ? '[' + key + ']' + value + ' - Yes' : '[' + key + ']' + value + ' - No';

    console.log(bgIco);

}
```

But it always comes back no

If in the includes function I manually put a number in the object instead of the **key** variable then it works, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Object properties are always *strings* (or symbols), even if they *look* like numbers when declaring them:

```js
const obj = { 1: 'foo' };

const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
console.log(key === 1);
console.log(typeof key);
```

So, map the `myColor` array to strings first:

```
var myColor = [3, 1].map(String);
```

Otherwise, the `includes` check will fail (since `includes` requires `===` - or SameValueZero - for a match to be found)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, I knew it was something there, but I couldn't figure out what

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the array against the object seems simpler to iterate the array instead

```js
var color = {
             1: "Red",
             2: "Blue",
             3: "Yellow",
             4: "Violet",
             5: "Green",
             7: "Orange"
            };

var myColor = [3, 1, 55];

for(let k of myColor){
   console.log(k, color.hasOwnProperty(k), /* OR */  k in color);      
}
```